# SQL statement for revoking administrator rights in Moodle

Tags: sql, moodle

Which SQL statement can I use to revoke the rights of an administrator (user ID: 1234) in Moodle?

Thx

Comment: `DROP TABLE USERS` DONE; Of course this is probably not what you tried but please post that so we may best assist you in fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

The list of site admins is stored in a comma-separated list in table (mdl_)config, so you can retrieve the current list with:

```
SELECT value FROM mdl_config WHERE name = 'siteadmins';
```

Once you have this value, you will be able to remove the unwanted ID from the list of IDs, then write it back again with:

```
UPDATE mdl_config SET value = '<updated value>' WHERE name = 'siteadmins';
```

After that, you will need to *purge the site caches*, for the new value to be used by Moodle. You can purge site caches using the CLI script:

```
php admin/cli/purge_caches.php
```

(Or via the user interface at: Site admin > Development > Purge caches)